# Is it possible to place all css in one line using gruntjs and/or lesscss?

Tags: node.js, less, gruntjs

All .js and .less files are builded in my project with gruntjs (built-in .js support) and grunt-less-contrib plugin for tasks with .less files.

For a moment lesscss compresses css  in one-definition-per-line style, for example for following .less file:

```
div,span,textarea,input {
  margin:0;
}
```

It will output:

```
div,
span,
textarea,
input {
  margin:0;
}
```

I want to compress all css into one line, for this example it should look like:

```
div,span,textarea,input{margin:0;}...other styles...
```

Is it possible? Any advice will be helpful, I am not sure that this is a question straight about lesscss or grunt.

Maybe it is possible to add a task after build.css is built, and then perform concatenation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The grunt-contrib-less plugin is also enough to minify the compiled CSS. You don't need another plugin to minify your code.

It has two options specific for this use-case:

- compress (will remove some whitespaces):

  ```
  less: {
      compile: {
          options: {
              paths: ["foo/bar/css"],
              compress: true
          },
          files: {
              "path/to/result.css": "path/to/source.less"
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less/#compress
- yuicompress (will run your CSS through css-min internally):

  ```
  less: {
      compile: {
          options: {
              paths: ["foo/bar/css"],
              yuicompress: true
          },
          files: {
              "path/to/result.css": "path/to/source.less"
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less/#yuicompress

So in your case "yuicompress" would be the right thing to add to your gruntfile.

Answer (score 2):

You can minify your CSS files with `grunt.js` using the module `grunt-css`

- Install the module with `npm install grunt-css --save-dev`
- Load the module in your `grunt.js` or `Gruntfile.js` (depending on the grunt version used) using
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-css');
- configure the task in the `Gruntfile.js` as,

  ```
  grunt.initConfig({
    less: {
      //YOUR LESS CONFIG
    },
    cssmin: {
      YOUR_TARGET: {
        src: 'SRC_PATH/input.css',
        dest: 'DEST_PATH/output.min.css'
      }
    }
  });
  ```
- you can combine and minify multiple css files using the following configuration,

  ```
  grunt.initConfig({
    less: {
      //YOUR LESS CONFIG
    },
    cssmin: {
      YOUR_TARGET: {
        src: 'SRC_PATH/**/*.css',
        dest: 'DEST_PATH/output.min.css'
      }
    }
  });
  ```
- Register your task with grunt build task, to run after the less task,

  ```
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['less', 'cssmin'])
  ```
- now you can either run `grunt build` or `grunt cssmin` to generate the minified CSS file.

The `grunt-css` modules has `csslint` built-in, so you can also add a task to lint your css files.

More configurations/options can be found at https://github.com/jzaefferer/grunt-css